# Link style to multilevel list level twice in MS Word?

Tags: list, formatting, ms-word

I am formatting a document in MS Word. I have my section chapters style linked to the 1st level in a multilevel list, with my sub-section heading styles linked to the 2nd and 3rd levels. There is custom text before the 1st level and the number format here is text while the number format for the 2nd and 3rd are numeral so it looks like this:
Chapter One
1.1
1.1.1

I have created a table style that links to the second level of a different multilevel list for now so it looks like this:
1.1
1.2
etc...

The first number (level) of the table multilevel list does not change because it is not linked to any style. I want this to change based on the chapter so when I am in chapter 1 the first table says 1.1 and when I am in chapter two the first table says 2.1 (with the second number resetting). My intuition is to link the chapter style from the other multilevel list. This is not working. MS Word is only letting me link one style to one level of one multilevel list. If I add it to a second one it is removed from the first one. Does anyone know how I can use the same style for two multilevel lists?

Your help is really appreciated, this is killing me!

Comment: Wouldn't linking the heading style to two lists cause the chapter numbering to increment prematurely anyway? If I understand correctly, you would rather want to use a SEQ field instead.